# Can't return multi-level resource/collection through API

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent, resources

Question:
How do I return values of a resource through another resource?
If I have a pivot table inbetween (many to many relationship), does something change, other than the model function `$this->hasMany(AnotherModel::class, 'pivottable')`
?

For example:

There's a table called "tags", and another table called "tagtranslations"

"tag" only has an ID and timestamps
"tagtranslations" has id, tag_id, title, slug and timestamps

There are TagResource and TagTranslationResource

In TagTranslationResource I'm returning the "toArray"

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

and in TagResource I'm returning

```
return          
        [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => TagTranslationResource::collection($this->title),
            'slug' =>  TagTranslationResource::collection($this->slug)
        ];
```

and in Controller I'm calling back Tag with tagtranslations

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $tags = Tag::with('tagtranslation')->get();
        //return $tags;

        return TagResource::collection($tags);
    }
```

when, in TagResource I call, for example

```
return [
  'title' => new TagResource($this->title),
  'slug'  => new TagResource($this->slug)
]
```

I only get null fields in my JSON api response

and the response I get for the

`'title' => TagTranslationResource::collection($this->title)`

is an error "Call to a member function first() on null"

Can someone please explain what's happening here? :D
I also tried with
 `TagResource::collection(TagTranslation::all())->$this->title`

but it can't convert to string

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it correctly the problem is:
TagTranslationResource::collection() expect to receive a collection and you are passing just the *title* and the *slug*.

How would I do it:

Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  return TagResource::collection(
    Tag::with('tagtranslation')->get()
  );
}
```

TagResource:

```
return [ 
  'id' => $this->id,
  'any_other_tag_field' => $this->any_other_tag_field, 
  'tagtranslation' => TagTranslationResource::collection($this->tagtranslation),
];
```

TagTranslationResource:

```
return [
  'title' => $this->title,
  'slug'  => $this->slug
]
```

If you want to know a bit more, here is the [link of the official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources)

And [here an article I wrote](https://medium.com/@macielthiago/eloquent-api-resources-12afb3a8e9d0) about api resources.

I hope it help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I already managed to solve it a few days after the question was asked and it's pretty much what you wrote so I'm giving you the rep for the answer ^_^